# Returning to parent activity's existing instance from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

I am creating a library project which has chat feature, so user has to register his launch activity as parent in order to perform backstacking(navigating back).
here is my manifest for sample app..

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ak.messages.ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

and here is how i am trying to navigate back from ChatActivity

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if(intent!=null){
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
//      super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

But its always creating a new instance. is there any way to ensure that same MainActivity's Instance gets revoked when user performs back-press?

> PS: Chat activity is not directly invoked by MainActivity I have
>   provided with APIs to launch it.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just finish() your activity in onBackPressed? If the starting activity had not finished itself when starting yours, then this will restart the former activity.

Comment: @dev.bmax it's an library project, if i receive notification or just launch the chat activity by intent, finishing it will close the app instead of launching it's parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to access/launch an activity with the help of intent actions:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if(intent!=null){
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setAction("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY");
            startActivity(intent);
        }super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

where user can get the action from the intent to handle..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try replacing

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

with

```
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

In this way you will resume the parent activity and will receive call back in `onNewIntent()` of `Parent Activity`